# Selected item transfer issue, There is no ViewData item of type

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am building ASP.NET MVC project, All other posts about this topic did not help me. i have 2 models, Client and City.

```
public class Client
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }     
    public City City { get; set; }       
}

 public class City
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And when i want to create a client a have an exception There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable' that has the key 'City'.

This is my get and post method

```
 private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

    private List<City> _cities;
    public ClientsController(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;

    }

// GET: Clients/Create
    public IActionResult Create()
    {
        if (_context.City != null) _cities = _context.City.ToList();
        ViewBag.Cities = new SelectList(_cities, "Id", "Name");


        return View();
    }

    // POST: Clients/Create
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Id,Surname,Name,Patronymic,Telephone,City,Adress,SeriaNumberPassport,IdentificalCode")]
        Client client)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _context.Add(client);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        return View(client);
    }
```

And View code:

```
<div class="form-group" mb-3>
            <label asp-for="City" class="control-label"></label>
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.City, ViewBag.Cities as SelectList, new { @class = "form-select" })
        </div>
```

The data is displayed correctly, but I cannot create a client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think that the `ModelState.IsValid` is `false`, hence it returns to `Create` View rather than redirect to `Index` view (the flow for successful inserting `Client`).

While for the failure inserting case, you didn't provide the `ViewBag.Cities` value before returning to `Create` View (Check the `Create` method with `[HttpPost]`).

Talk about why the `ModelState.IsValid` was `false`, there is conflict in the type that you are passing `CityId` which is `int` type to `City` property with `City` type.

**Updated:**

Recommend creating and using the ViewModel class instead of Model. The main reason is to we can design the class in which the properties are only required for view, create/edit purposes.

Exposing the Model class is unsafe as the users will know how is your database entity looks like.

But the *trouble* with using ViewModel will be you need to map the property value from ViewModel to Model manually or with reflection. Of course, there are open-source libraries that can automate the mapping such as [AutoMapper](https://automapper.org/).

---

These are the steps you need to do for the fix:

> Model

1. Add for `CityId` foreign key property.

```cs
public class Client
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } 
    public int CityId { get; set; }  // Add this foreign key property    
    public City City { get; set; }       
}
```

*Note: If you use Entity Framework Code First approach, you need to create migration and update the database via command for this change.*

> ViewModel

Create ViewModel class with the properties require for Create Client.

```cs
public class CreateClientModel
{
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }  
    public int CityId { get; set; }

    // Other properties that needed
}
```

> View

2.1. Change the `@model` to `CreateClientModel`.
2.2. Use `model.CityId` instead of `model.City`. The `CityId` property is used to pass the selected city's Id.

```
@model CreateClientModel

<div class="form-group" mb-3>
    <label asp-for="CityId" class="control-label"></label>
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CityId, ViewBag.Cities as SelectList, new { @class = "form-select" })
</div>
```

> Controller

3.1. Replace `City` with `CityId` in `Bind` attribute. (To add properties based on `CreateClientModel`).

3.2. Use `CreateClientModel` as request body.

3.3. Initialize the `ViewBag.Cities` value before returning to `Create` view for the `ModelState.IsValid` is `false` case.

```cs
public IActionResult Create()
{
    if (_context.City != null) _cities = _context.City.ToList();
    ViewBag.Cities = new SelectList(_cities, "Id", "Name");
      
    return View(new CreateClientModel());
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Surname,Name,CityId")]
    ClientClientModel client)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // Perform mapping from CreateClientModel to 
        _context.Add(new Client
        {
            Surname = client.Surname,
            Name = client.Name,
            CityId = client.CityId
            // Other properties
        });
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }

    // Initialize ViewBag.Cities value
    if (_context.City != null) _cities = _context.City.ToList();
    ViewBag.Cities = new SelectList(_cities, "Id", "Name");

    return View(client);
}
```

Suggested have a read and follow this tutorial which is similar to your scenario:

[Tutorial: Update related data - ASP.NET MVC with EF Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/update-related-data?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

Comment: Thanky you. But i have one more problem with this now. When i try to create client, in my post method object City = null and client cant be created because modelstate.isvalid = false

Comment: Hi, sorry for that, I update the answer. Would suggest using ViewModel instead of Model for your View and Controller. Then perform a mapping from ViewModel to Model.